# How to get data from JWT if didn't have users table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, jwt, microservices

I try to implement microservice arhitecture.Because I new in it,can maybe someone can tell me:
- can I use JWT for communication to services,when someone login into one service.Is that secure way or there is something better?
- how do I parse JWT and get user id or some other data from it to have it in other service which didn't have users table?Like is it expiried,user id...

Thank you a loot if someone can help me to send me a direction for it.

Comment: Do you have some code that we can look at?

Comment: Code is still not written because I didn't know is that possible and is that OK direction. JWT will be generate in one microservice with laravel passport and I ask is that secure to use JWT over communication between microservice and how to get user Id and some more data like organization_id.. from that JWT .. because in other microservices I didn't have users table or authentication process like I have in first one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to the `tymon/jwt-auth` package for this, which largely uses 'namshi/jose' under the hood.  As long as the `jwt.secret` is the same between each system that may need to use the tokens, you should be able to just call `JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray()` to decode them.

You do need a user table, but it doesn't have to be *the* user table already speced out in Laravel.  Any Model that implements the `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` interface, such as by extending the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` model will do.

If you want to inject additional data into the token beyond the user table that the login credentials are being validated against, just add an array as the second parameter to the login attempt:

```
//The key names here are defined by the return values of methods described in the Authenticatable interface.
$credentials = [
    'username' => 'your_user',
    'password' => 'your_password'
];
$customClaims = [
    'someOtherDatapoint' => 'more_data'
];
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, $customClaims);
```

You could also go directly to the token-creation without authentication:

```
$user = app(YourUserModel::class)->first($id);
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user, $customClaims);
```

This is relatively secure, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to communicate encrypted data.  You might want to just use the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` helper functions, that are based off the APP_KEY.  You could also look at Laravel-Passport, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport, for authentication, which uses OAuth2.

Comment: Thank you @Claymore I thinking to add passport in oath server which will generate JWT which I will use to talk with other services in different servers. I just try to figure out best way to validate token to able access resources from other services, I don't want to someone who didn't access to comes to some information or data.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that OAuth2 via Passport would produce JWT tokens.  Oauth2 and JWT are similar in that they both use 'bearer tokens'.  And that they're both used for authentication.  But they're completely different methods of getting that behavior.  You could think of JWT as a replacement for session-cookies, and it's typically used by "single-page apps" that don't really have their own back-end.  Whereas OAuth2 is a method of handling authentication _and_ authorization.  In either case, I wouldn't tack on encrypted form-data to the bearer tokens.  Just make that a separate request.